# .NET WCF permissions

Tags: .net, wcf

I have setup a .NET WCF web service that will expose some methods to create/update email alerts for different contactsIds. The webservice is going to live behind the firewall.

My fear is that if we expose a call like:

```
bool SetAlertTemplate(int alertId, int templateId);
```

One of the client websites could modify unintentionally an alert that does not belong to the contactId that is using the website.

Even if i use:

```
bool SetAlertTemplate(int alertId, int contactId, int templateId);
```

It could create a problem in the future if we expose the webservice to the public. Where anyone could modify any alert.

What is the best way to expose a webservice and be sure that the client has permissions to modify the alert of a contactId, and hopully not sending these parameters with every call.

Answer (score 1):

Configure your WCF service to translate the authenticated user to a proper [IPrincipal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.iprincipal.aspx) instance. This ensures that in the rest of the call stack, [Thread.CurrentPrincipal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.currentprincipal.aspx) will represent the authenticated user.

From your description it sounds like you need to protect assets (alerts), which means that you will need to implement **Access Control Lists** (ACLs) on the assets.

Whenever anyone attempts to modify the asset, you can check whether Thread.CurrentPrincipal is allowed to modify that particular asset according to its ACL.

Related answers:

- [Permissions Design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030177/permissions-design/2030825#2030825)
- [Architechture of service application in WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064191/architechture-of-service-application-in-wcf/2064268#2064268)
- [How to save user object in WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2093983/how-to-save-user-object-in-wcf/2094067#2094067)